# Possible to skip text entry if value exists in a form using selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this issue.

I am trying to come up with a way to fill a form that has 100+ fields.

If I was using Selenium IDE or Webdriver is there a way to skip entering text in fields that already contain values?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
if(field.getText().equals(""))
    field.sendKeys("something")
```

Note: this is pseudo-code!